# Most Efficient Way to Search Text Files for Multiple Terms in Bash

Tags: bash, grep

I'm writing a bash script that is looking for person names in text files. What's the most efficient way in Bash to search a text file using a dictionary of names?

If it was only a few names, I'd do:

```
#!/bin/bash
namearray=(jon bob sue mary)

function findnames {
for name in ${namearray[@]}
do
  grep $name $filename
done
}

if [ ! -z findnames ]
then
echo "$filename has person name"
fi
```

But, if I was trying to find hundreds of names against hundreds of files, that doesn't seem like the most efficient means, or with Bash is it?

Comment: how many names in total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "-f" option is your friend.

If the list of names is in a file (say names.txt), with each name on a separate line,  then instead of running `grep $name $filename` for each $name in names.txt as in your example, you could run `grep -f names.txt $filename`.  You might want to use fgrep instead, and you might want to include other options (e.g. -w).

If the list of names is not in a file, then you might want to use the form `-f <( ... )` to avoid having to create a temporary file.